# JNA callback method wont be called until futureTask.get() timeout

Tags: java, callback, jna, futuretask

If I run like this, the callback block will not run so `future.get()` will block forever:

```java
FutureTask<Long> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(System::currentTimeMillis);

boolean login = CameraSDk.login(ip, port, userName, password, 
       (lLoginID, pBuf, RevLen, EncodeType, CmdSerial, dwUser) -> {
    //do something
    futureTask.run();
});

try {
    Long timestamp = futureTask.get();
    System.out.println("timestamp = " + timestamp);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But if I use this:

```java
Long timestamp = futureTask.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The callback block will be called when `futuretask.get()` times out.

I don't know what happened, is this a dead lock or something else?

Comment: `FutureTask` with a single argument is documented to take a `Callable` argument.  I don't see how your `Long` parameter implements the `Callable` interface.  What is the `call()` method implementation associated with this `FutureTask`?

Comment: `Callable<Long> callable = new Callable<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call() throws Exception {
                return System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        };
`

`FutureTask<Long> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
`